# Facebook description issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have integrated Facebook with my Android app. Implemented Posting functionality in my app.

I have posted successfully. But problem is it displays description for a fraction of a second until a page is loaded completely. Once page is loaded then it doesn't display description.

What could be the problem ?

You can see this problem by loading this profile page. https://www.facebook.com/bhavesh.thakrar.3

Comment: Just to warn you. Every single post looks the same so I assume you are pre-filling the message. That is not allowed by the platform policy which means that either your app will be banned or restricted.

Comment: I am using this to post Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", params,
      HttpMethod.POST, callback);
are you saying that this is now allowing any more?

Comment: I'm saying that your app is not allowed to set the message. The user have to type the message them self. Please read Platform Policy 2.3: "Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments, and captions."

Comment: I am not displaying Facebook native share dialog box to user. I am asking them to post in custom alert. If they press yes then I am posting from code entirely. Is this not allowed?

Comment: Did the user enter the message? If they did it is allowed. If they didn't it is not allowed.

Comment: No. User hasn't entered a message. But I did ask for permission to post.

Comment: I assume you didn't read the policy or even the quote I made. If the user didn't type the message it is against policy.

Comment: I am following this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share. Search publishStory(). I am using something like that which will not display any alert to user.

Comment: not sure what that have to do with anything